# How to add an admin to 13.04

Tags: 13.04

Through some way I have completely erased all accounts from my laptop. When I try to add a new admin account it asks for the root password. I've tried my password from my previous account and it didn’t work. What do I do to get an admin account back?

Edit: I'm logged in through a guest account right now.

Edit: I have access to recovery mode but I'm not Sure how to get into the root account.  Hasiya Rulzz, I tried this but I don't have any accounts to change the password on and it didn't work with the root account.

Edit: I am not able to download the rescue cd

Comment: So, now, how you are logged in? With which account?

Comment: reset your forgotten password follow this guide : http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/linux/reset-your-forgotten-ubuntu-password-in-2-minutes-or-less/

Answer (score 1):

Unless you specifically set one, your root account probably does not have a password - the assumption being that you would log in as someone else and use `sudo`.

The guest account probably cannot use `sudo`, as that would be all sorts of badness.

Can you download and boot from the System Rescue CD (http://www.sysresccd.org/)?

Before you boot, do `df /` to work out which partition your root file system is on. e.g.

```
$ df /
Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1     192114204 101260032  81088596  56% /
```

tells me I need to remember `/dev/sda1.` I am assuming for the moment you are not using logical volumes as that adds a few steps in the next bit.

Now boot from the system rescue CD - this will (eventually) take you to a root prompt.

Now mount the root file system:

```
# mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
```

There are two ways to go here...

Simple - edit /mnt/etc/shadow, and remove root's password, change:

```
root:!:15842:0:99999:7:::
```

to

```
root::15842:0:99999:7:::
```

(note the missing `!`)

After this you should be able to reboot to Ubuntu and log in as root without a password (remember to set a root password after you log in!).

Complicated - If that does not work - then go back to system rescue and remount your root partition. Then try these commands:

```
# chroot /mnt
# passwd root
```

That should change the root password. Reboot, and log in as root.

Answer (score 1):

When you first turn your computer on, and your BIOS finishes posting, hold down the <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> key.  That should bring-up your GRUB menu.  From that menu, select your most-recent kernel update that finishes with the text "(recovery mode)."  That should bring-up the recovery menu, where you can select the option to "Drop to root shell prompt."

Once there, you may have a read-only filesystem.  If you do, you'll need to mount it:

```
mount -o remount,rw /
```

Next, create your new admin user and give it a password.

```
useradd newAdmin
passwd newAdmin
```

Then, add your new admin user to the sudo group.

```
adduser newAdmin sudo
```

Change your directory to "home" and make sure your new user has a home directory:

```
cd /home
ls -al
```

If one doesn't exist for the new admin user, add it and give the new admin user ownership of it:

```
mkdir newAdmin
chown newAdmin newAdmin
chgrp newAdmin newAdmin
```

Reboot, login as your new user, and you should be "good."